# Xcode issue. Classes not recognized in one project, but in other project works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, nsobject

I was working on a simple project, just few files. I went to the restroom and after I came back something wrong was done. Xcode stopped recognising any class or object I would create.

To better explain, I tried to create a new Action sheet but it wouldn't recognise the class, so I tried to see if it was just stuck and I removed an `UIAlertViewDelegate` from a class ( it was working before, and was still in purple color, as a recognised element ) but after deleting it wouldn't recognise it again if I would try rewriting.

I tried restarting the comp, restarting Xcode, I tried deleting the Derived Data. Nothing worked.

If I open another project, it works just fine, so something must be wrong in that one project.

what can be?

the only few things that it recognise are few protocols, app delegate, primitive types, filter generators, raw byte, my own classes, arrays...

I'm totally lost. it seems like it's missing a reference, like it won't import some frameworks ( `UIKit` n so on ) Can it be something in build settings ?

this is all the code...

FirstViewController

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    let _siteUrl = "http://www.google.it"

    @IBOutlet weak var _spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var _webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         _webView.delegate = self
        loadSite()
    }

    func loadSite(){
        let requestUrl = NSURL(string:_siteUrl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestUrl!)
        _webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    _spinner.startAnimating()
        return true
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        println("Did finish load")
        _spinner.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: please show you code it's better to  we help to You

Comment: edited to show the code, but i don't think it's a code issue, i tried to remove all the code, to restore it to the base code that Xcode opened when i used the Tabbed bar controller...and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "fix" xcode. Sometimes it works.
Look at https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Fixing-Xcode